# hostapd on yocto krogoth

Tags: yocto, hostapd

I have a linux system which is build with yocto. I have do add the hostapd package to the system. With `bitbake hostapd` I am able to build the package and I can install the package and the dependencies on the target and it works. Now I want to add it to the base image and so I added the line `IMAGE_INSTALL += "hostapd"` to the base image file. When I build the base image i see that the package hostapd is build but then I get the following error message. Does someone knows that failure?!

> ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command
>   build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg --volatile-cache -f
>   build/tmp/work/var_som_mx6_-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-image/1.0-r0/opkg.conf
>   -o /build/tmp/work/var_som_mx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-image/1.0-r0/rootfs
>   --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install iputils ipvsadm liberation-fonts htop rsyslog kernel-modules openvpn qtbase ethtool
>   evtest swupdate-signing-key qtbase-plugins shadow util-linux dtc opkg
>   tzdata-atlantic freeradius tzdata-europe net-snmp-server
>   packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh u-boot-fw-utils fontconfig-utils
>   libinput qtwebengine iptables invm kernel-module-sitronix boost ntp
>   tzdata-pacific iperf3 i2c-tools run-postinsts net-snmp-client
>   dual-boot-tools openssl tzdata-misc lsof tzdata-antarctica fbv
>   qtwebengine-qmlplugins perf ntpdate tzdata-arctic tzdata-americas
>   tzdata bridge-utils tcpdump dosfstools nfs-utils u-boot-splash hostapd
>   owfs ifenslave resolvconf packagegroup-core-boot alsa-utils alsa-tools
>   sudo valgrind tzdata-africa e2fsprogs daemontools openssh-sftp-server
>   alsa-lib ecasound nfs-utils-client qtdeclarative-tools swupdate
>   alsa-plugins cronie stress tzdata-australia usbutils tzdata-asia
>   pciutils iproute2 base-passwd' returned 255:
>
> Installing hostapd (2.5-r0) on root.
>   Downloading file:/build/tmp/deploy/ipk/cortexa9hf-neon/hostapd_2.5- 
>   r0_cortexa9hf-neon.ipk.
>
> To remove package debris, try `opkg remove hostapd`.
>
> To re-attempt the install, try `opkg install hostapd`.
>
> Collected errors:  * preinst_configure: Aborting installation of
>   hostapd.  * opkg_install: Cannot install package hostapd.
>
> DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished ERROR: Function failed:
>   do_rootfs

Comment: Try clean using `bitbake -c cleanall base-image` and re-build it.

Comment: I tried the cleanall and I tried to delete the whole build and did a new one but the failure is still there!

Comment: Can you check the name of ipk hostapd packages generated? They should be in build/tmp/deploy or build directory as specified for your build setup? Are the hostapd packages split into component packages?

Comment: Yes the ipk package is generated and I am able to install the package but there a lot of dependencies so I want to integrate it in the main swu package.